# tensorflow error OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:625 : UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found

Tags: cudnn

To build the deep learning server, we used NVIDIA 535, CUDA 12.1, Cudnn 8.8.1, and Tensorflow 2.15.0. However, the DNN library is not found error occurred. We have encountered this problem before, so we checked the version and verified it, but the same problem occurred. Please help me.\

(We also confirmed that the GPU is recognized as normal.)

When I installed and executed the above version, I thought that the CNN code would run normally, but the DNN library is not found error occurred.